# Measuring nanoamp range current consumption

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, low-power, power-measurement

I am looking to buy one of [Joulescope](https://www.joulescope.com/), [ZS-2102-A](https://www.anglercircuits.com/product-page) (angler circuits) or [Otii](https://www.qoitech.com/) (QOITech) to measure power consumption and get graphs of current consumption for some low power BLE/WiFi devices. Does any one have experience with these devices?

Circuit under test consumes between a few nanoamps to 400 mA @ 7.4 V input.

I have looked at [EEVblog](https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/) microcurrent etc., I really need the software which graphs consumption in real time without the use of a scope.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Those products look perfect suitable, you should buy one of them. This site is more for electronics design, i.e. how to build one.

Comment: 8 to 9 orders of magnitude range will be quite a challenge. I've had to achieve that range (though my range was from 10 fA to 7 uA.) But you wouldn't be able to use the devices I used. The IC aluminum paths will suffer unacceptable migration when the current exceeds 7 uA (my top end was determined by the IC and I had to speak with the designer to get this limit from him.) You have some fun ahead.

Comment: Voting to close as shopping questions are off topic. However, I'll quickly comment my personal recommendation: I've always used the Agilent power analyser from Keysight. Great bit of kit: https://www.keysight.com/en/pc-1113932/dc-power-analyzer?cc=US&lc=eng

Comment: As well as what Bryan says - consider drawing power from a capacitor and watch the delta V with time. Longer more intervals allow you to get averages. You can run on battery or power supply with power fed via a switch and cap on load side of switch. Open switch and note how fast voltage falls. Or you could have a device which opened a switch and reclosed it when cap V fell by a given amount. The time between open close gives current.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar problem by switching shunt resistors, e.g. 0.1 ohms (switched) in parallel with (in my case) 10 kilohms.

In normal operation I measure voltage across the 0.1 ohm shunt. At 400mA that drops 40 mV, which is small compared with the variability in battery voltage.

When the equipment goes to sleep, I open the switch and measure voltage across the 10 kilohm shunt. That was fine for my purposes; hundreds of nA. Adjust values to suit expected current range and voltage measurement equipment, adding a third shunt if necessary.

If it wakes up with the switch open, and 10 kilohms in series with the power supply, it'll crash, of course. So don't do that...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this platform is for electronics design, rather than purchase recommendation and product review.

I would personally reccomend buying the Otii. It delivers the most features for the price, e.g. best price/value range. Also it comes with a 14-day trial licencse for battery evaluation. Maybe this would also be interesting for you, to see how your device performs on batttery.

Please note that measuring current in the nA range, is not a trivial task.